# Riot Api - How can I bring the data of user in other regions?

Tags: json, riot-games-api

I am trying to get user data from other regions using [Riot Api](https://developer.riotgames.com/api-methods/)

I am able to get a data from North America region but not able to bring user data from other regions such as Brazil.

I have found about [regional endpoints](https://developer.riotgames.com/regional-endpoints.html) but how I can use this to bring user data from specific region?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some options here:

**Option #1**: If you use Riot's UI in the [Full Api Reference](https://developer.riotgames.com/api-methods/), then there is a dropdown list for every endpoint to select a different region from:

[image: Riot API UI]

**Option #2:** If you build the request URL yourself, then you have to use the specific host from the [table for regional endpoints](https://developer.riotgames.com/regional-endpoints.html). So, for example, if you want to see the featured games list for the brazil region, then you have to get the host 'br1.api.riotgames.com', add the endpoint '/lol/spectator/v4/featured-games' to it and add your apikey as a query paramater. Like that:

```
https://br1.api.riotgames.com/lol/spectator/v4/featured-games?api_key=<your_apikey>
```

That option is described [here](https://developer.riotgames.com/getting-started.html).

**Option #3**: Use one of the many api wrappers in your favourite programming language. I myself am using [this one in Java](https://github.com/taycaldwell/riot-api-java). With such an api wrapper you can make a request for featured games like that:

```
ApiConfig config = new ApiConfig().setKey(<your_apikey>);
FeaturedGames games = RiotApi(config).getFeaturedGames(Platorm.BR1);
```